# How to put working buttons in a databound control

Tags: asp.net, webforms, custom-controls, postback, page-lifecycle

If I make my own custom control, I have to make sure I add all controls in the OnInit, or else postbacks won't work. ProcessPostData is called between Init() and Load(), so if I add my controls in Load(), the post data step has already been done before my control was on the page.

However, if I put a button in an ASP.NET repeater and only bind data to the repeater in Page_Load(), the repeater triggers the ItemCommand event, even though the control was not on the page during Init. How does this work? How do I make my own custom control that adds buttons to the control in Load() or PreRender()?

I want something like this:

```
public class WrappedButton : WebControl
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        var button = new Button { Text = "Hello" };
        button.Click += SomeCommand;
        Controls.Add(button);
    }

    private void SomeCommand(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Response.Write("This won't get executed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have WrappedButton inherit from button?  You may also want to try inheriting from CompositeControl, which is meant to work with child control collections explicitly.

Comment: In this example I have one button, but actually I want a number of buttons. The number of buttons varies, depending on a datasource.